# I'm looking to improve the code I use to copy down data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some code made by recording a macro in Google Sheets. It does a copy and paste of data into a column. But it's a clumsy way to copy down and I'd like to do it better.

I currently use this code.

```
    function import2() {

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Road MT'), 
    true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();   
spreadsheet.getRange('Imported!A2:A').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

I have also used code similar to below, but the problem with this code is that it throws an error if the rows don't actually exist. It's doesn't create new rows to fill the data.

```
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('\'Round Up\'!F:F').activate();
      spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('@')
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      range.getRange("\'Road MT\'!AF2").setFormula('=\'Round Up\'!F2');

      var lr = range.getLastRow();
      var fillDownRange = range.getRange(2, 32, lr-1);
      range.getRange("\'Road MT\'!AF2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

Comment: So you want to copy the value from Road MT A2 into the entire column of Imported?

Comment: Haha, no, the range is poorly defined as A2:A. So the whole of column A to wherever it ends. That might be different for each set of data.

Comment: Does your data every have blanks?

Comment: No blanks until the end

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve]. Please provide complete functions, an example spreadsheet and a thorough explanation of your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a script to do something like that. It won't create row your way, but if you know the range of what you are pasting, you can set the range of the data to copy to be rows that don't exist yet and it will make them.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //this get what you want to copy and it's length
  var sheetToCopy = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(<name>); //or similar
  var rangeToCopy = sheetToCopy.getRange(<yourRange>)
  var dataToCopy = rangeToCopy.getValues()
  var nRowsToCopy = dataToCopy.length // or rangeToCopy.getLastRow()
  var nColsToCopy = rangeToCopy.getLastColumn() //because dataToCopy[0].lenght might vary from dataToCopy[5].lenght

  //this get get where you wanna copy it and set the proper range so it can be pasted
  var fillDownSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(<name>); //or similar
  var fillDownRow = fillDownSheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var fillDownRange = fillDownSheet.getRange(fillDownRow, <yourColIndex>, nRowsToCopy, nColsToCopy);

  //this paste your data
  fillDownRange.setValues(dataToCopy);
```

Alternatively, you could also use the copyToDestination() [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) like so :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var sheetToCopy = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(<name>); //or similar
var rangeToCopy = sheetToCopy.getDataRange()
var nRowsToCopy = rangeToCopy.getLastRow()
var nColsToCopy = rangeToCopy.getLastColumn()

var fillDownSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(<name>); //or similar
var fillDownRow = fillDownSheet.getLastRow();
var fillDownRange = fillDownSheet.getRange(fillDownRow, 1);
var fillDownGridID = fillDownRange.getGridId();

rangeToCopy.copyValuesToRange(fillDownGridID, 1, nRowsToCopy, fillDownRow, (fillDownRow+nColsToCopy))
```

But you need at least one empty row on your sheet or it's going to overwrite it.

Comment: updated answer with 2nd way that's a bit closer to what you already have

Comment: No prob, it got me frustrated too first time I wanted to do that. Especially since their doc isn't very specific tbh.